# Open Google Map at the click of a button in Android!

Tags: java, android, xml, google-maps, android-mapview

There are 3 buttons on the screen! Start, View Map, Stop

When I click View Map, it should go to a new screen that shows the map! But something goes wrong and the app is getting force closed! I believe the problem is with the xml files. Please someone correct it.

Main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TextView 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:id="@+id/widget35" 
android:padding="10dp" 
android:textSize="35sp" 
android:text="Maps" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button 
android:textSize="30sp" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:id="@+id/buttonStart" 
android:text="Start" 
android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <Button 
android:textSize="30sp" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:id="@+id/buttonMap" 
android:text="View Map" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button 
android:textSize="30sp" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:id="@+id/buttonStop" 
android:text="Stop" 
android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.google.android.maps.MapView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:id="@+id/mymap"
    android:apiKey="xxxxxxxxxxx" />

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/myzoom"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="Firstdroid.Gps"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0">
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
<activity 
android:name=".MainActivity"
android:label="@string/app_name">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
<service 
android:permission="android.permission.INTERNET" 
android:name=".IntentService" 
android:enabled="true"
/>
<service android:name="GPSTestApp" />
<activity android:name=".MapViewer">
</activity>
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
</manifest>
```

### MainActivity.java

```
package Firstdroid.Gps;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.MyLocationOverlay;
import Firstdroid.Gps.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    MapView myMap;
    private MyLocationOverlay myLocOverlay;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        /* MAP BUTTON */

        Button mapButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonMap);
        mapButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View m){
                    Log.d("Firstdroid.Gps", "Loading Map..");
                    // Loading Google Map View
                    startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MapViewer.class));
                }       
        });

    }
}/* End of MainActivity */
```

In addition to the Map button block, this also has blocks for start and stop, but they work correctly.

### MapViewer.java

```
package Firstdroid.Gps;
//import android.R;
import Firstdroid.Gps.R;
import android.app.Service;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.MyLocationOverlay;
public class MapViewer extends MainActivity {

    MapView myMap;
    private MyLocationOverlay myLocOverlay;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        initMap();
        initMyLocation();
    }

    private void initMap() {
        myMap = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mymap);

        View zoomView = myMap.getZoomControls();
        LinearLayout myzoom = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.myzoom);
        myzoom.addView(zoomView);
        myMap.displayZoomControls(true);

    }

    /**
     * Initialises the MyLocationOverlay and adds it to the overlays of the map
     */
    private void initMyLocation() {
        myLocOverlay = new MyLocationOverlay(this, myMap);
        myLocOverlay.enableMyLocation();
        myMap.getOverlays().add(myLocOverlay);

    }

    //@Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Logcat

```
06-29 04:34:37.701: WARN/dalvikvm(381): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
06-29 04:34:37.731: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(381): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-29 04:34:37.731: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(381): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{Firstdroid.Gps/Firstdroid.Gps.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21: Error inflating class com.google.android.maps.MapView
06-29 04:34:37.731: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(381):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
06-29 04:34:37.731: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(381):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
06-29 04:34:37.731: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(381):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
06-29 04:34:37.731: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(381):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
06-29 04:34:37.731: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(381):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-29 04:34:37.731: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(381):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-29 04:34:37.731: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(381):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
06-29 04:34:37.731: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(381):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-29 04:34:37.731: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(381):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-29 04:34:37.731: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(381):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
06-29 04:34:37.731: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(381):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
06-29 04:34:37.731: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(381):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-29 04:34:37.731: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(381): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21: Error inflating class com.google.android.maps.MapView
06-29 04:34:37.731: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(381):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:576)
06-29 04:34:37.731: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(381):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
06-29 04:34:37.731: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(381):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
06-29 04:34:37.731: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(381):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
06-29 04:34:37.731: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(381):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
06-29 04:34:37.731: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(381):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:198)
06-29 04:34:37.731: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(381):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1647)
06-29 04:34:37.731: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(381):     at Firstdroid.Gps.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23)
06-29 04:34:37.731: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(381):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
06-29 04:34:37.731: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(381):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
06-29 04:34:37.731: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(381):     ... 11 more
06-29 04:34:37.731: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(381): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.maps.MapView in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/Firstdroid.Gps-2.apk]
06-29 04:34:37.731: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(381):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
06-29 04:34:37.731: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(381):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
06-29 04:34:37.731: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(381):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
06-29 04:34:37.731: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(381):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:466)
06-29 04:34:37.731: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(381):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:565)
06-29 04:34:37.731: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(381):     ... 20 more
06-29 04:34:37.751: WARN/ActivityManager(58):   Force finishing activity Firstdroid.Gps/.MainActivity
06-29 04:34:38.292: WARN/ActivityManager(58): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{44fb8580 Firstdroid.Gps/.MainActivity}
06-29 04:34:48.824: WARN/ActivityManager(58): Activity destroy timeout for HistoryRecord{44fb8580 Firstdroid.Gps/.MainActivity}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a separate layout .xml file for your map view.  Create a new xml called map.xml in res->layout and past this in.

Note: your MapViewer class should extend a MapActivity, not a MainActivity.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:orientation="horizontal"
>

<com.google.android.maps.MapView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/map_view"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:clickable="true"
android:enabled="true"
android:apiKey="your API key goes here" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Make sure you set the content view to the new file in your map activity.

```
setContentView(R.layout.map);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is it! I have 2 xml files now.. main.xml and map.xml
But now when I click view map button, the app is getting force closed!

06-29 22:53:00.966: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8365): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-29 22:53:00.966: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8365): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Firstdroid.Gps.MapViewer
06-29 22:53:00.966: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8365):     at Firstdroid.Gps.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:48)
........................................................
06-29 22:53:00.986: WARN/ActivityManager(96):   Force finishing activity Firstdroid.Gps/.MainActivity

Answer (score 2):

i think you missed this code:

```
 <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

in you android manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case the error occurs on the emulator: You may have missed to install the "Google API" package for your platform and/or use that as your build target and/or didn't start the *Google API* emulator.

The CNFE for `com.google.android.maps.MapView` is a hint.

---

[Here is a tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html) that demonstrates the use of `MapView`. Check if this runs in your target system (no `ClassNotFoundException`), if yes, you have a template/pattern for your own application.

Comment: Yes! I ran it seperately and it worked. When I tried to bring it into my app, i don't know...something goes wrong!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure if this is the problem, but I think that you're inflating everything twice.  Why does your MapViewer extend MainActivity instead of Activity, and why don't you have two XML files, one with a layout for the main activity and one with a layout for the map viewer?

When you call the onCreate() method for MapViewer, you make your super call through first.
That means that you are effectively calling `setContentView()` via the same resource file twice because you're calling the SetContentView from MainActivity.  I could be wrong, but I think that when you create your first MainActivity before hitting the button, you are creating the MapView and then making its parent the MainActivity.  When you create the MapViewer activity, you are then trying to reinflate the view without removing it from the parent activity and reparenting it.

And even if everything I just said is totally wrong, it's *terrible* to have two activities sharing one layout file.  If the activities both have the exact same layout, then they should be one activity to begin with and you should rethink your approach.

Comment: Yes! I've created another xml file and now the layout is fine. But when I click View Map button, I get this error, 06:33:07.024: WARN/dalvikvm(300): Unable to resolve superclass of LFirstdroid/Gps/MapViewer; (37)
06-30 06:33:07.035: WARN/dalvikvm(300): Link of class 'LFirstdroid/Gps/MapViewer;' failed
06-30 06:33:07.045: ERROR/dalvikvm(300): Could not find class 'Firstdroid.Gps.MapViewer', referenced from method Firstdroid.Gps.MainActivity$2.onClick
06-30 06:33:07.045: WARN/dalvikvm(300): VFY: unable to resolve const-class 8 (LFirstdroid/Gps/MapViewer;) in LFirstdroid/Gps/MainActivity$2;

Comment: Sounds like you didn't rewrite your imports after changing the way MapViewer subclasses.